# CentOS 7 elixir distribution missing Enum.sum/1

Tags: elixir

This is a odd.  I was orking with elixir on a CentOS 7 machine.  As I was going through some examples, I got the following error:

```
iex(1)> Enum.sum([0])
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Enum.sum/1
    (elixir) Enum.sum([0])
```

Why is it missing?  Is there another package I need to install?  I could find nothing in the "googlesphere'.

Comment: What version of Elixir? `Enum.sum` has been around for a while, but maybe you're running a _really_ old version.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ never ever use language packs coming with a distro from official repos. Use [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) or whatever else version manager of your choice instead.

Answer (score 0):

The version that comes in the CentOS rpm is Elixir 0.12.5.  So, I am assuming that version is missing Enum.sum/1.  I will install it from source.

Thanks Roger Lipscombe.

Comment: I installed Erlang and elixir from their git repositories.  All good.